# How do I copy the value of an HTML element to another value of an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

> Write a function named "inputCopied" that doesn't take any parameters and doesn't return a value. This function should find an HTML element with an id of "user", which will be a text box, and set this value as the HTML inside an element with an `id` of "copied".

```
function inputCopied() {
    var y = document.getElementById('copied');
    return y.value = 'user';
}
```

How do I copy the value of an HTML element to another value of an HTML element? My code doesn't seem right.

Comment: Please also be sure to mark up things you're quoting as quotes (put `>` and a space at the beginning of the line). I've added quoting for what I believe is you quoting the assignment, please use the "edit" link on the question to correct it if I've got it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get both inputs by `id` attribute using `getElementById()` method and save them to separate variables, then get the value of `user` input using the `.value` property and assign it to the `copied` element using `textContent/innerHTML`.

**NOTE:** Use `innerHTML` if you want to assign value as HTML.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', inputCopied);

function inputCopied() {
  var user = document.getElementById('user');
  var copied = document.getElementById('copied');

  copied.textContent = user.value;
  //Or 
  //copied.innerHTML = user.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="user" value="User name here">

<button id="button">Copy value</button>
<br>
<span id="copied"></span>
```

Comment: They can learn by examples...

Comment: @epascarello I find it off putting to help in ANY way on Stackoverflow cos of people like you.  The amount of negative energy and time you have spent downvoting and commenting, you could have spent in 1 Qtr by giving a useful and helpful response.  Is he going to learn by ignoring him and downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
function inputCopied() {
    //find an HTML element with an id of "user
    var user = document.getElementById('user');

    // which will be a text box
    var userTextboxValue = user.value;

    //set this value as the HTML inside an element with an id of "copied"
    document.getElementById('copied').innerHTML = userTextboxValue;

}
```